# Getting a partial String Vector 2D array into another pointer vector array

Tags: c++, string, vector, multidimensional-array

I'm building a CSVParser Library (using similar to Excel OLE objects), to be implemented using Vectors

the cell array is saved as a multi dimension string array in the main class CCSVParser

```
static vector< vector< string> > CellArray;
```

and another pointer array inside the CRange Class

```
vector< vector< string> >* RangeCells;
```

**Edit : the purpose of using a pointer array is to save allocated space, since the library may handle large amount of data**

inside the GetItem method of CRows class , i need to return a Range object with its pointer array pointing to the addressed row of the main CellArray

```
CRange* CRows::GetItem(int idxRow)
{
    CRange* retRange = new CRange ;

    retRange->RangeCells = (vector< vector<string> >*)&CCSVParser::CellArray[idxRow] ;

    return retRange;
}
```

the vector array pointer works fine when pointing to the whole array

```
retRange->RangeCells = (vector< vector<string> >*)&CCSVParser::CellArray ;
```

but fails addressing just a row in the CellArray

**Note :** RangeCells pointer array needs to be multi-dimensional, since in other operations it may return a set of rows

Any ideas how to fulfill this???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If `CellArray` is a vector of vectors (of strings), then `CellArray[i]` is a vector (of string). However, you try to assigning its address to a pointer to a vector of vectors (of strings) and that is not possible.

The address of a vector is not the same as the address of a vectors of vectors.

`RangeCells` should be declared as

```
vector<string> *RangeCells;
```

I'm guessing it will work much better.

Comment: Thank you , as obvious , i'm a newbie to vectors
may you tell me how to dynamically change RangeCells (initially defined as an address of vectors ) to be an address of a vector of vectors
as i might explained , the range object may contain more than just a row , that's why i chose the multi-dim (vector of vectors)